# Bypassing responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've recently starting coding my layout with responsive properties. I personally HATE mobile websites, but to accommodate my visitors, I've decided to make my site responsive.

What I cant figure out is how to disable responsive properties when I want to.

I want a link on the top of my page that when clicked will toggle the mobile site on/off.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you don't show that you at least tried, and what you tried, this will get voted to be closed. Also (pure interest) why do you hate mobile websites?

Comment: You probably want to use media queries? Failing that when the user clicks your link toggle a class on the html/body element and then prepend all your mobile css with html.mobile

Comment: I've tried searching everywhere, but seems like no one wants to do things the way I do! Even using the 'View in desktop mode' on my mobile browser, I can't bypass my responsive design. I don't like mobile versions because I feel restricted. I'm totally fine with a normal web design, since I can easily pinch and zoom into the content I'm interested in!

Comment: i think that removing (or messing with) the `meta viewport` element would be worth a shot.

Comment: I'm kind of looking for a way to set the visitor's viewport, so my site will just show the normal site design. (If the user clicks on the 'View normal site' link)

Comment: @pawel Removing the meta viewport tag seems to have no effect on the site at all :/

Comment: The viewport meta tag only has effect on mobile devices, testing it on the desktop won't work. I'm not sure if it's a good solution to the problem though, I'd have to test it.

Comment: @StephanMuller I'm alson ot sure if it is good solution or not, but meta viewport exists, IMO, for exactly this purpose. For example if your design requires at least 1000px, then `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1">` instructs the mobile browser to create a 1000px wide viewport.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that comes to mind is a JavaScript (/ jQuery) function that adds or deletes a CSS file from the HTML lay-out when the switch is one way or the other. You would have to make a separate CSS file that only contains your responsive media queries but that shouldn't be a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a server-side language, one way to do this is to provide a link with query information such as `http://mywebsite.com/?full=1` for viewers who want to view the full site. You would check to see if the variable `full` exists in the query data and check if its `1`. If it is, then you would set a related `full` session variable to true. Then whenever a page is loaded, check to see if the session variable `full` is true. If it is, then serve the "Full CSS" file. If it isn't, serve the "Responsive CSS" file. You could use cookies instead of session variables I believe. I'm a little rusty in the server-side department.

You could also do this in JavaScript using cookies.

Comment: Do I really have to work out two separate CSS files? Is there no way to set a user's viewport?

Comment: The easiest way will be to have two separate CSS files. You could have one file specifically for the mobile responsive side that gets added or removed based on your link. However, in any of these cases you will need to keep track of your visitors' settings because once they go to a new page, if you're not keeping track of their preferences, it will load the responsive page by default. That requires either JavaScript or a server-side language.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to put the responsive parts of your stylesheet in a separate file, for instance `responsive.css`. Then you can bind a javascript function to a link that toggles that stylesheet:

In the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css" id="responsiveStyle">
```

In the `<body>`:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleResponsive()">Toggle</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggleResponsive() {
   var responsiveStyle = document.getElementById('responsiveStyle');
   if(responsiveStyle.rel === "stylesheet") {
      responsiveStyle.rel = "";
   } else {
       responsiveStyle.rel = "stylesheet";
   } 
}
```

Comment: I would also like to recommend that if you're using JavaScript, you should save their preference in a cookie so that when they go to another page on your website, it will still be toggled correctly.

Comment: That's a good point, but not defined in the question. Would be a nice addition though.